# how to pass fieldset contents from html to html

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code in page html1,

```
      <fieldset id="bill1">
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="serviced"><b>Service :</b></div>
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="tratyped"><b>Type of Transport :</b></div>
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="custyped"><b>Type of Client</b></div>
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="datepickerd"><b>Date :</b></div>
        <div  style="font-size:9px;display:none" id="timed"><b>Time :</b></div>
        <div  style="font-size:9px" id="departured"><b>Departure Address :</b></div>
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="destinationd"><b>Arrival Address</b></div>
      </fieldset>
```

The innerhtml values of those divs will change at runtime.

How can I send or view these information in another page html2.

I want to be able provide the fieldset contents inside the page "html2" from "html1", which is included (include 'html2') into the "php1" page.

Please help me with the coding or just give your suggestions, I will try to code it myself.

Thanks!

Edit............

Inside fare.html

```
     <fieldset id="bill2" style="padding-top:0">
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="passengerd"><b>No. of Passengers :</b></div>
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="shairwelld"><b>No. of Chariwells :</b></div>
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="babycd"><b>No. of Baby Chairs :</b></div>
        <div style="font-size:9px" id="companiond"><b>No. of Companions :</b></div>
     </fieldset>
```

In pay.html

```
     <fieldset id="bill2">
     </fieldset>
```

I used the jquery code inside head tag as

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bill2').load('/fare.html #bill2')
})
</script>
```

The above code works...

It loads the default content of the fieldset. But not loading the values produced during run time. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com) you can use `.load()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bill2').load('/html1.html #bill2')
})
```

Where `#bill2` is the id of fieldset from `html2.html` in which you want to load fieldset `#bill2` from `html1.html`

Comment: I tried your code, but the fieldset in html2 page is empty. It didn't load the content. I will edit the question with how I tried it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: It still didn't work, I also double checked the id's to make sure I spelled everything correctly, but the fieldset is not loading the content. I updated the questions with what I have tried so far. Thanks for helping.

Comment: This works for me. What do you have in fare.html? What do you have in #bill2 of flare? In #bill2 of page where you use script?

Comment: is there any mistake in the way I specified jquery? <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Comment: Do you have jquery in the folder you have your html file?

Comment: I don't have it. I am confused with how to use this jquery code.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks a lot. The mistake was, I forgot to upload the edited fare.html page. Sorry!

Comment: I am facing another problem, the pay.html page loads the default fieldset contents in fare.html but it is not loading content produced during run time. Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a hidden form with javascript and submit it.
When you want to use GET, you can also add those parameters to the current url with javascript and load this url.

Comment: I have to pass the values from html to html to php, since there is a html page in the middle I am unable to use get and post please help me with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I like your "Please help me with the coding or just give your suggestions, I will try to code it myself.

You can do it with form,

Create a form with some hidden fileds, while submitting that form get the `div`'s inner html and make that as hidden value using javascript and submit that form.

Comment: I have to pass the values from html to html to php, since there is a html page in the middle I am unable to use get and post please help me with your suggestions.